# Vertical Scrollbars are returning the opposite values of what they should in Java applet

Tags: java, scrollbar, awt

I have a java applet in early stages with 2 vertical scrollbars. When one is changed, the other follows suit and the labels next to them are updated to the values of the scrollbars. This works, but the values returned are flipped from what they should be. In the initialization of the scrollbars, the maximum and minimum are the correct values and placed correctly in the statement. When the bars are dragged up to the maximum value, the minimum is displayed in the label and vice versa. I don't know if I initialized something wrong or if the math behind calculating the values to be displayed is wrong.

As a note, all the numbers being used are representative or either degrees Fahrenheit, Kelvin, or Rankin.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Exam2 extends Applet implements AdjustmentListener
{
    //variables from the HTML file
    String unit = "K";
    double temp = 0;
    Dimension APPSIZE = this.getSize();

    //variables for temperature
    double curK, curR;
    double fmin = -50.0, fmax = 250.0;
    double minK = (fmin + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0);
    double maxK = (fmax + 459.67) * (5.0/9.0);
    double minR = fmin + 459.67;
    double maxR = fmax + 459.67;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    //graphics objects
    Scrollbar Kbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.VERTICAL, (int)minK, 10, (int)fmin, (int)fmax);
    Scrollbar Rbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.VERTICAL, (int)minR, 10, (int)fmin, (int)fmax);


    Graphics ColorBar;
    Label KelvinText = new Label("Kelvin");
    Label RankinText = new Label("Rankine");
    Label curK_text = new Label();
    Label curR_text = new Label();
    Label maxK_text = new Label(String.valueOf(df.format(maxK)));
    Label maxR_text = new Label(String.valueOf(df.format(maxR)));
    Label minK_text = new Label(String.valueOf(df.format(minK)));
    Label minR_text = new Label(String.valueOf(df.format(minR)));

    //runtime variables
    boolean running = true;

    public void init()
    {
        Dimension appsize = (APPSIZE);
        double colweight[] = {1,1,1,1,1};//3
        double rowweight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//8
        int colwidth[] = {1,1,1,1,1};//3
        int rowheight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//8
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.rowHeights = rowheight;
        gbl.rowWeights = rowweight;
        gbl.columnWeights = colweight;
        gbl.columnWidths = colwidth;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        setBounds(0,0,480,640);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
        Panel k = new Panel(gbl);
        Panel r = new Panel(gbl);
        Panel drawingpanel = new Panel();

        //add objects
        //Kelvin label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.KelvinText,c);

        //maxK_text
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.maxK_text,c);

        //Kbar
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.Kbar,c);

        //minK_text
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 8;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.minK_text,c);


        //Rankin label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.RankinText,c);

        //maxR_text
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.maxR_text,c);

        //Rbar
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.Rbar,c);

        //minR_text
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 8;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.minR_text,c);

        //curK_text
        curK_text.setAlignment(Label.RIGHT);
        curK_text.setVisible(true);
        curK_text.setText("0");

        //curR_text
        curR_text.setAlignment(Label.LEFT);
        curR_text.setVisible(true);
        curR_text.setText("0");

        //curR_text
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 9;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.curR_text,c);

        //add items
        k.add(this.KelvinText);
        k.add(this.maxK_text);
        k.add(this.Kbar);
        k.add(this.minK_text);
        r.add(this.RankinText);
        r.add(this.maxR_text);
        r.add(this.Rbar);
        r.add(this.minR_text);

        //add listeneers
        Kbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        Rbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);

        //draw bar
        ColorBar = drawingpanel.getGraphics();

        //add to screen
        add(curK_text);
        add(k);
        add(drawingpanel);
        add(r);
        add(curR_text);
    }

    public void run()
    {       
        //get the unit
        try{unit = getParameter("UNIT", "K");}
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        //get the temperature 
        try{temp = getParameter("TEMP", 0);}
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        //make sure temp is initialized
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("k"))
            {
                temp = minK;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = minR;
            }
        }

        //initial conversion to initialize scrollbars
        if (unit.equalsIgnoreCase("K"))
        {
            curK = temp;
            curR = curK * (9/5);
        }
        else if(unit.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            curR = temp;
            curK = curR * (5/9);
        }
        else
        {
            stop();
            System.err.println("An invalid unit was given for UNIT. The applet is now terminated.");
        }

        //set text labels
        curK_text.setText(String.format(df.format(curK)));
        curR_text.setText(String.format(df.format(curR)));

        //set initial values of scrollbars

        Kbar.setValue((int)curK);
        Rbar.setValue((int)curR);
        while (running)
        {

        }
    }   

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
    {
        Object s = e.getSource();
        int newvalue;
        if (s == Rbar)
        {
            newvalue = Rbar.getValue();
            Kbar.setValue(newvalue);
            Rbar.setValue(newvalue);

            curK = (newvalue + 459.67)*(5.0/9.0);
            curR = newvalue + 459.67;   
            curK_text.setText(String.valueOf(curK));
            curR_text.setText(String.valueOf(curR));    
        }
        if (s == Kbar)
        {
            newvalue = Kbar.getValue(); 
            Kbar.setValue(newvalue);
            Rbar.setValue(newvalue);

            curK = (newvalue + 459.67)*(5.0/9.0);
            curR = newvalue + 459.67;   
            curK_text.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(curK)));
            curR_text.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(curR)));
        }
    }   

    public void stop()
    {
        Kbar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
        Rbar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    }   

    //overridden getParamater methods
    private String getParameter(String key, String def)
    {
        String t;
        return (t = getParameter(key))!=null ? t : def;
    }   

    private int getParameter(String key, int def)
    {
        Integer t;
        return (t = Integer.valueOf(getParameter(key)))!= null ? t.intValue() : def;
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main problem seems to be min is top and max is bottom of your vertical scrollbar.  The quick way to fix this would be to simply change your label to reflect the difference

```
curK_text.setText(String.valueOf(minK + maxK- curK));
curR_text.setText(String.valueOf(minR + maxR - curR));
```

This only fixes the displayed text issue.

Comment: success! The display is really all I needed, so this is just what i needed.

Comment: Curious, though, you said the Main Problem is that Min is Top and Max is bottom.  Is there any way to flip this?

Answer (score 1):

In your adjustmentValueChanged() method you need to "reverse" the input value to the calculation to account for your maximum and minimum.

So, after this line:

```
Rbar.setValue(newvalue);
```

In the "(s == Rbar)" block, you need:

```
newvalue = Rbar.getMaximum() + Rbar.getMinimum() - Rbar.getValue();
```

In the "(s == Kbar)" block, you need:

```
newvalue = Kbar.getMaximum() + Kbar.getMinimum() - Kbar.getValue();
```

Comment: hm well that does work in regards to the values displayed in the labels, but the animation of the slider's bubble is reversed. (When the bubble is slid up, it appears to move downward, and then snaps to its position when you let go of the mouse)

Comment: I didn't experience that problem as long as the newvalue variable is re-assigned after the 'Rbar.setValue(newvalue)' lines as described, but I agree that @SF has a cleaner solution.